# How would I Import Borderlands 2 textures into UDK for mod?

Tags: unreal-development-kit

So I was looking to create a mod/own levels for borderlands 2 not commercial use or anything and the developers said they are happy for people to mod the game so legal issues shouldn't be a problem, but I was wondering how I would go about getting the game assets (mainly textures AI templates would be a bonus) into Unreal Development Kit to play around with?
Any help greatly appreciated.
P.S. I know of programs such as TextMod but they seem to take them out of screanshots i was looking for a way to get them out of game files.

Comment: Allowing people to mod the game and allowing them to extract and use assets like textures are two completely different things. I wouldn't be so sure that extracting textures (for another game/project even non commercially) is legal.

Comment: http://www.gamefront.com/gearbox-no-borderlands-2-official-tools-but-modding-encouraged/ thats a link to what the devs said about modding part of it says they are happy for people messing with its game and that they encourage modding so while im aware reverse engineering software is normally illegal they seem to give permission in terms of allowing you to mod just they are not offering support for you to do this (dlc is worth more than a modding community nowadays sad fact but true) just wanted to mess around with lvl design for a fpsmoba without starting skill trees and textures from scratch

Comment: Judging from the gamefront link, you are on the safe side. Sorry, I don't know how to extract assets from Borderlands 2. I just wanted to make sure that you won't run into legal trouble. ;-)

Comment: Yea i should of put link in origional post to clear up any legal conerns seems that nobody knows how to extract them yet.